# Why does gcc add extra vmovdqa64 instructions with _mm512_dpbusds_epi32?

Tags: c++, gcc, intel, avx512

`g++` is generating extra move instructions and I'm not sure why.  [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/47vELM)

This is happening around the [_mm512_dpbusds_epi32](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm512_dpbusds_epi32&expand=2210) intrinsic.  The instruction computes 8-bit dot products then adds them to a packed 32-bit accumulator (in this case with a saturating add).  The instruction is a bit unusual in that it both reads from and writes to the accumulator.

When compiled with gcc, the compiler is emitting extra move instructions (`vmovdqa64`) on the accumulator.

Here's a test program that accumulates some dot products:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstddef>
__m512i Slow(const __m512i *a, const __m512i b0, const __m512i b1, std::size_t count) {
  __m512i c0 = _mm512_setzero_epi32();
  __m512i c1 = _mm512_setzero_epi32();
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    c0 = _mm512_dpbusds_epi32(c0, a[i], b0);
    c1 = _mm512_dpbusds_epi32(c1, a[i], b1);
  }
  // Do not optimize away
  return _mm512_sub_epi32(c0, c1);
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -O3 -mavx512vnni example.cc -S`, this is the main loop:

```
.L3:
  vmovdqa64 (%rdi), %zmm6
  vmovdqa64 %zmm3, %zmm0
  vmovdqa64 %zmm4, %zmm2
  addq  $64, %rdi
  vpdpbusds %zmm5, %zmm6, %zmm0
  vpdpbusds %zmm1, %zmm6, %zmm2
  vmovdqa64 %zmm0, %zmm3
  vmovdqa64 %zmm2, %zmm4
  cmpq  %rdi, %rax
  jne .L3
```

The above assembly is copying an accumulator from `zmm3` to `zmm0`, updating `zmm0`, and copying it back to `zmm3`.  This is unnecessary; it should just use one of `zmm0` or `zmm3` as an accumulator.

The problem is the same on `g++ (Gentoo 9.2.0-r2 p3) 9.2.0` and `g++ (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0`.

`clang++` 9.0.1 avoids the unnecessary copying (it also unrolled the loop, but here is the tightest version.)

```
.LBB0_6:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  vmovaps (%rdi), %zmm4
  vpdpbusds %zmm0, %zmm4, %zmm3
  vpdpbusds %zmm1, %zmm4, %zmm2
  addq  $64, %rdi
  addq  $-1, %rax
  jne .LBB0_6
```

I was able to work around the problem in `g++` by using inline asm.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstddef>
__m512i Fast(const __m512i *a, const __m512i b0, const __m512i b1, std::size_t count) {
  __m512i c0 = _mm512_setzero_epi32();
  __m512i c1 = _mm512_setzero_epi32();
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    asm ("vpdpbusds %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(c0) : "x"(a[i]), "mx"(b0));
    asm ("vpdpbusds %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(c1) : "x"(a[i]), "mx"(b1));
  }
  // Do not optimize away
  return _mm512_sub_epi32(c0, c1);
}
```

The loop `g++` generates for `Fast` is much better:

```
.L3:
#APP
# 7 "asm.cc" 1
  vpdpbusds (%rdi), %zmm3, %zmm0
# 0 "" 2
# 8 "asm.cc" 1
  vpdpbusds (%rdi), %zmm1, %zmm2
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
  addq  $64, %rdi
  cmpq  %rax, %rdi
  jne .L3
```

Comment: Missed-optimization bugs are a thing, unfortunately.  GCC and clang both sometimes trip over themselves and waste some `mov` instructions.  This looks worse than normal, though.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.  It's a bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94663 probably in the integrated register allocator.